# SQl query in MS Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

Ok SQL experts. I have a table with a column of zip codes and a column of the StCou the zip code resides in.  If there is more than one record for the same zip code and all of these records reside in the same StCou than thats an error in the file that I would like to find. Heres an example of what the table looks like and what the error would look like.

```
Zip    StCou
06410  09011
01880  25017
01880  25017
00601  72001
```

In this example the error is the zip code 01880. Again if there are more than one record for the same zip and it lies in the same county then only 1 zip code record should be displayed. I want to find these errors in my file. The StCou values are FIPS code and they are in text format. I am working with this file in MS Access.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
Select Distinct Zip, StCou
From YourTable
```